# Applying CSS to anchors within footer

Tags: html, css, anchor, footer

I'm working on an assignment and I can't seem to apply styling to my anchor elements within footer. Here's my HTML and CSS - I tried `footer nav a{}` and the following configuration:

```css
.footer-content nav a {
  margin: 100px;
  color: yellow;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer-content">
    <h3>Sweet Eats Bakery</h3>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Cookies</a>
      <a href="#">Weddings</a>
      <a href="#">Catering</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
    <p class="copyright">&copy; Sweet Eats 2018</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I did try your code here, and it seems to work. Maybe you have another css that is overriding this one?

Comment: Here's the rest of the css applied to the footer section:


footer {
  width: 100%;
  background: #F87B99;
  border-top: 1px dashed white;
}

footer .footer-content { 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  width: 600px;
}

footer .footer-content h3 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

footer nav {
  display: flex;


.footer-content nav a {
  margin: 100px;
  color: yellow;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

footer nav a:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

footer .footer-content .copyright {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

Comment: Run the Snippet,  everything is working as it should.

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket after your **footer nav** properties, though that only had a minor impact on the rendering, so I'm not sure that was your issue.

Comment: @Chris, that was it. Thank you